# Problems with memory allocations, string etc

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory, allocation

I'm having problems with these three parts of codes, in the terms of Memory Allocations. I haven't got it yet.

Could you please point out to me what I am doing wrong and how I should go on correcting it?

1:

```
class MyString {
public:
    MyString()  : str(0) {}
    MyString( char *a ) 
    { str = new char[strlen(a)+1]; strcpy(str,a); }
    ~MyString() { delete[] str; }
private:
    char *str;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const MyString &str);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const MyString &s)
{
    return os  << s.str  << endl;
}

int main()
{
    MyString str("Mitt namn");
    MyString *strp = &str;
    // alot of code
    delete strp;
    // alot of code
}
```

2: Defined as above

```
int main()
{
    MyString *str1 = new MyString("Mitt namn");
    MyString str2  = *str1;
    delete str1;
    // alot of code
    cout << str2 << endl;
}
```

3: Still defined as above

```
class MyASCII : public MyString {
public:
    MyASCII( char *a) : MyString(a), ascii(0)
    { 
        if (a==0) return;
        ascii = new int[strlen(a)];
        for (int i=0; i<strlen(a); i++)
            ascii[i] = int(a[i]);
    }
    ~MyASCII() { delete[] ascii; }
private:
    int *ascii;
};
```

Comment: Well, what is the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, just use `std::string`. Secondly, Rule of Three violation. Thirdly, you `delete` a local variable in 1's `main`, which is wrong.

Comment: can you be more specific on where the problems is??

Comment: @Stabbah Delete all of that code and use `std::string` instead.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Okay, I got that. But in the second one, what am I doing wrong there?

Comment: @Stabbah: You violated the Rule of Three.

Answer (score 2):

1. C++ has a built in string class, `std::string`, why don't you use it?
2. Your assignment semantics are broken. You need an assignment operator and a copy constructor that copy the memory held by `str`.

   In C++ it's essential to have consistent copy-constructor, assignment and destructor. This is the [Rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) DeadMG referred to. You should read the related question [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

   When copying `MyString`, your code makes a shallow copy. So both instances share the same data. Once you destroy the first instance, the second one has a dangling pointer.
3. Your code sample 1 assigns a pointer to a local variable to `strp` and then tries to delete it. You can only free memory that was allocated with `new MyString(...)` with `delete`.

   The destructor of local variables are destroyed automatically once they pass out of scope. You don't need to (and can't) free them manually with `free`.
4. Code sample 2 would be fine, if your class were implemented correctly. It uses the copy constructor to copy the heap allocated string to a local variable. But since your copy contructor doesn't actually copy the memory, it's broken as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. Done. Closed case.